# No command line interface on HDMI but kernel logs printed

Tags: pi-3, linux, hdmi, terminal, buildroot

I'm currently trying to build my own custom Linux OS for my Raspberry Pi 3 and am experiencing some trouble.

I'm using buildroot v2018_2.

I configured the system using `make raspberrypi3_defconfig`

Then just changed the following options :

- C library : use `glibc` instead of `uClibc-ng`
- Increased filesystem size from 60M to 100M
- Add password `root` to root user under `[*] Enable root login with password`

After compiling, flashing the generated `sdcard.img` and booting, I can see kernel logs on the HDMI connected screen.

However after booting, the OS doesn't propose any prompt on the HDMI screen and I'm stuck here.

I know that the system is not freezed because I can see kernel logs if I plug/unplug my keyboard.

I suppose that the console is connected to the UART and only kernel logs are sent to HDMI port.

However I can't find how to force console prompt on HDMI.

Here are my config.txt and cmdline :

---

```
$ cat config.txt
# Please note that this is only a sample, we recommend you to change it to fit
# your needs.
# You should override this file using a post-build script.
# See http://buildroot.org/manual.html#rootfs-custom
# and http://elinux.org/RPiconfig for a description of config.txt syntax

kernel=zImage

# To use an external initramfs file
#initramfs rootfs.cpio.gz

# Disable overscan assuming the display supports displaying the full resolution
# If the text shown on the screen disappears off the edge, comment this out
disable_overscan=1

# How much memory in MB to assign to the GPU on Pi models having
# 256, 512 or 1024 MB total memory
gpu_mem_256=100
gpu_mem_512=100
gpu_mem_1024=100

# fixes rpi3 ttyAMA0 serial console
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

---

```
$ cat cmdline
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200
```

---

I didn't change any configuration in kernel and I'm using the one from raspberry-pi github repository.

Does someone know how I could get a prompt on the HDMI screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gerard H. Pille and his clue about `/etc/inittab` file, I could find a solution which is described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=157836)

Seems that for having HDMI console, two tricks have to be done:

- `console=tty1` shall be after `console=ttyAMA0,115200` in `cmdline.txt`
- In `/etc/inittab` only one console in enabled.

There may have a better solution which allow to have several getty into `/etc/inittab` but this solution is sufficient for me right now.

Comment: I only have console=tty1 in my cmdline.txt, never understood why one would have two of them.  Isn't it always the last one that counts?  In /etc/inittab I've got 6 consoles - 7 is for X - and I can login on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line as follows to your /etc/inittab:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

but perhaps your speed should be 115200 iso 38400

Comment: Tried but still the same result. I already had a line for HDMI console in my inittab `tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  tty1 0 vt100 # HDMI console`

Comment: `/etc/inittab` is part of the deprecated `SysV` init boot system. I don't know what you have compiled but `Raspbian` comes since years (Jessie) with 'Systemd' init system. There isn't anymore a `/etc/inittab` in official images. You should really consider to use `systemd` and check its services for output on consoles.

Comment: No systemd on my systems, I stick to Devuan, I prefer to know what's going on.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, do you mean `Debian`?

Comment: @jsotola, no, D e v u a n. Only older people like me are allowed to use it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devuan VUA = veteran unix administrators.

Comment: oh, old dogs that like the old tricks ... lol ... that's me also